# MYSQL select all data table a if clause table b is met

Tags: mysql

> I have a table like below

```
+-------+   +----------+
| HOTEL |   | LOCATION |
+-------+   +----------+
| 1     |   | 1        |
| 2     |   | 2        |
| 3     |   | 3        |
| 4     |   | 4        |
| 5     |   | 5        |
+-------+   +----------+

+-----------------+
| HOTEL_LOCATION  |
+-----------------+
| 1     | 1       |
| 1     | 2       |
| 1     | 3       |
| 2     | 4       |
| 3     | 5       |
+-----------------+
```

I want to select the hotel and all locations if clausa location is
met. For example: I want to select hotels and all locations by
location = 1

> I want is output:

```
+-----------------+
| HOTEL_LOCATION  |
+-----------------+
| 1     | 1       |
| 1     | 2       |
| 1     | 3       |
+-----------------+
```

> The output I got was :

```
+-----------------+
| HOTEL_LOCATION  |
+-----------------+
| 1     | 1       |
+-----------------+
```

> Previously I apologize with my bad English
>
> Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: paste the code you have tried

Comment: Can you post the actual SQL you are executing? (also, if you'd go all the way and setup a runnable example on http://sqlfiddle.com/ people would greatly appreciate)

Comment: This my query :

SELECT h.hotel_nama, 
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT lh.lhotel_lokasi_id SEPARATOR ",") AS hotel_lokasi 
FROM hotel h 
LEFT JOIN lokasi_hotel lh ON lh.lhotel_hotel_id = h.hotel_id 
WHERE lh.lhotel_lokasi_id = 1 GROUP BY h.hotel_nama

Comment: please check the following link


http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2df63/6/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two issues with:

```
SELECT h.*, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT l.lokasi_name SEPARATOR ",") AS hotel_lokasi
  FROM hotel h
       LEFT JOIN lokasi_hotel lh ON lh.lhotel_hotel_id = h.hotel_id
       LEFT JOIN lokasi l ON l.lokasi_id = lh.lhotel_lokasi_id
       WHERE lh.lhotel_lokasi_id = 1
 GROUP BY h.hotel_nama
```

### 1

`WHERE lh.lhotel_lokasi_id = 1` implies that `lh.lhotel_lokasi_id IS NOT NULL`, which makes the `LEFT JOIN` pointless.

To keep the `LEFT JOIN`, you should use:

```
  FROM hotel h
       LEFT JOIN lokasi_hotel lh ON lh.lhotel_hotel_id = h.hotel_id AND lh.lhotel_lokasi_id = 1
```

but really what you want here is a regular inner join, as you certainly don't want to see all hotels.

Conceptually, you can think it like this: conditions in the `ON` clause are applied to the joined table before joining, while conditions in a `WHERE` clause are applied to the result set, after joining.

### 2

`WHERE lh.lhotel_lokasi_id = 1` means you want to only see rows pertaining to location `1`, which is not actually the case: in fact, you want to see all rows *pertaining to hotels that are present in location `1`*.

You have two steps to go through:

1. find out what hotels are present in location `1`
2. select those hotels only (with info on their locations, if need be)

### in conclusion

I guess you want something like:

```
SELECT h.*, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT l.lokasi_name SEPARATOR ",") AS hotel_lokasi
  FROM hotel h
       JOIN lokasi_hotel lh ON lh.lhotel_hotel_id = h.hotel_id
       JOIN lokasi l ON l.lokasi_id = lh.lhotel_lokasi_id
 WHERE h.hotel_id IN (SELECT lhotel_hotel_id FROM lokasi_hotel WHERE lhotel_lokasi_id = 1)
 GROUP BY h.hotel_nama
```

Equivalently, you could replace the `IN` with a second join on `lokasi_hotel`:

```
SELECT h.*, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT l.lokasi_name SEPARATOR ",") AS hotel_lokasi
  FROM lokasi_hotel lh_filter
       join hotel h ON lh_filter.lhotel_hotel_id = h.hotel_id
       JOIN lokasi_hotel lh ON lh.lhotel_hotel_id = h.hotel_id
       JOIN lokasi l ON l.lokasi_id = lh.lhotel_lokasi_id
 WHERE lh_filter.lhotel_lokasi_id = 1
 GROUP BY h.hotel_nama
```

Comment: thank you for helping me, and your answer is very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If what you're saying is that a location can have multiple hotels and you'd like to select by location, your

```
+-----------------+
| HOTEL_LOCATION  |
+-----------------+
| 1     | 1       |
| 1     | 2       |
| 1     | 3       |
| 2     | 4       |
| 3     | 5       |
+-----------------+
```

is reversed and should be

```
+-----------------+
| HOTEL_LOCATION  |
+-----------------+
| 1     | 1       |
| 2     | 1       |
| 3     | 1       |
| 4     | 2       |
| 5     | 3       |
+-----------------+
```

UPDATE - after your comments:

I think what you want is this:

```
SELECT h.*, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT l.lokasi_name SEPARATOR ",") AS hotel_lokasi FROM lokasi_hotel lh1, hotel h, lokasi l, lokasi_hotel lh2
WHERE lh1.lhotel_lokasi_id = 1
  AND h.hotel_id =  lh1.lhotel_hotel_id
  AND lh2.lhotel_lokasi_id = l.lokasi_id
  AND lh2.lhotel_hotel_id = lh1.lhotel_hotel_id 
GROUP BY hotel_nama
```

it yields:

```
Hotel            ... Lokasi
----------------     ---------------
Dian Hotel           Dekat Pusat Kota,Dekat Jalan Pantura
Hotel Dedy Jaya      Dekat Pusat Kota,Dekat Wisata,Dekat Jalan Pantura
```

You need to join lokasi_hotel twice.  Once to identify the hotels in the region specified, and once to yield other locations of those hotels.

Also, I don't see that your `LEFT JOIN`s are necessary. I believe that they're just confusing your logic. `INNER JOIN`s (or equivalent, as I provided) connect tables where your tables are designed to always match on ids.

Comment: I should also say that the query that goes with this is `SELECT * FROM HOTEL_LOCATION where location = 1`, which gives the result you asked for.  But it sounds like I've misunderstood what your tables represent and what you're looking for.  Could you set up a http://sqlfiddle.com if it's something more complex?

Comment: please check the following link

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2df63/6/0

Help me, I've tried but it did not work

Comment: I see that you're getting two results.  This matches the two hotels at location 'Dekat Pusat Kota' according  to your "lokasi_hotel" table.  Can you tell me what you expect to get?

Comment: what I expect is to bring up all the lokasi of the hotel because in the hotel_nama: Dian Hotel has the lokasi : Dekat Pusat Kota, Dekat Jalan Pantura

Comment: Looks like you're already satisfied, but I've added my solution in case its of any help.  Cheers!